# Where can i read more about Rails 3.2's Data Store with key-value in textfield?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Where can i read more about Rails 3.2's Data Store feature, in which there's the option to store key-value in a textfield mentioned here:

[Is there a best practices/coherent way to update a database field that contains a hash key-value store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963090/is-there-a-best-practices-coherent-way-to-update-a-database-field-that-contains)

This is a seperate question because i was not able to comment on previous question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nice blog post on the subject: http://rawonrails.blogspot.com/2012/02/using-activerecordstore-with-rails-32.html