# Making virtual attributes be part of one Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model which has one actual column in the database. This column is stored as a JSON string of configuration. I use a bunch of virtual attributes which I want to map inside of this configuration JSON attribute. I basically dont want to create a bunch columns in the db, but rather use this one JSON attribute to contain everything. Is there a cleaner way than the below `def`s of achieving this?

```
class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :configuration
  serialize :configuration, JSON

  attr_accessor :background_color, :title

  # below is ew
  def background_color; self.configuration["background_color"]; end
  def background_color=(value); self.configuration["background_color"] = value; end

  def title; self.configuration["title"]; end
  def title=(value); self.configuration["title"] = value; end
end
```

Ideally i'd be looking for something like `attr_maps_to_hash :configuration, [:background_color, :title]`. Does something like this exist?

Comment: Another workaround I came up with is to use a `class_eval` on an array of attribute symbols to generate the getters and setters, but that's kind of ugly too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ActiveRecord::Store](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html) for this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  store :settings, accessors: [ :color, :homepage ]
end

u = User.new(color: 'black', homepage: '37signals.com')
u.color                          # Accessor stored attribute
u.settings[:country] = 'Denmark' # Any attribute, even if not specified with an accessor

# Add additional accessors to an existing store through store_accessor
class SuperUser < User
  store_accessor :settings, :privileges, :servants
end
```

If you are using PostgreSQL, check out [HStore](https://github.com/engageis/activerecord-postgres-hstore).

Comment: this is good. problem though is that ActiveRecord::Store doesn't declare these as `attr_accessible` which will result in "ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: background_color, title". This is expected, since I might want some attribs to be inaccessible. But i guess this means i'd need to have a separate `attr_accessible` line with the same array (or a var with the array used in both `attr_accessible` and `store_accessor`)

Answer (score 1):

Rails as of 3.2 has key-value stores built into ActiveRecord-see here:

[Where can i read more about Rails 3.2's Data Store with key-value in textfield?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563282/where-can-i-read-more-about-rails-3-2s-data-store-with-key-value-in-textfield)

in your case you can have a text field named configuration and then do this:

class Device < AR::Base
  store :configuration, accessors: [:title, :background_color, ...]
...

This should work fine with forms, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Two methods come to mind.

First, you could have an array of your attributes [:background_color, :title] and then iterate over them while calling define_method. You would defined two methods, define(method_name) and define("#{method_name}=").

Second, a similar idea but using method missing.

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
  ...see if it's a get or set...
  ...do your stuff...
  ...rain dance...
  ...yay...
end
```